# I cannot boot into linux, everytime I try I get these errors and it's stuck

Tags: boot, command-line, mount, login

```
/dev/sda5: clean, xxxxx/xxxxx files, xxxxx/xxxx blocks
[      7.387324] systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysusers.service:22: Executable "systemd-sysusers" not found in path "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
[      8.904221] systemd[250]: systemd-remount-fs.service: Failed to execute command: No such file or directory
[      8.923207] systemd[1]: Failed to start Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
[FAILED] Failed to start Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
[      9.077551] systemd[256]: systemd-randomseed.service: Failed to execute command: No such file or directory.
[FAILED] Failed to start Load/Save Random Seed.
[FAILED] Failed to activate swap /swapfile.
[FAILED] Dependency failed for Swap.
[FAILED] Failed to start Apply Kernel Variables.
```

This also happened after an e2fsck run, just in case that might help.
And I also wanted to explain what happens in more detail, everytime I boot up, I get those error messages for a brief time then it goes to a blank screen tty1 that says "{my username} login:" and everytime I login it says something along the lines of "Currently booting up system unprivileged users can't login." And it says after that incorrect password even though I'm 100% it's correct, any help?

Comment: This sounds like a dead storage device. I hope you have backups ...

Comment: is my hard drive dead?

Comment: btw when i start recovery mode i notice  file aystems are always read only

Comment: When Linux detects problems with a storage device it will mount them as read only so that you can try and copy important files off. I would suggest grabbing a Live USB/DVD, booting from there, and doing some disk diagnostics. This will give you a more definitive answer about the condition of your storage device.

Comment: i ran a smartctl test from recovery mode and it says it passed the health test. is that good

Comment: That's not a very thorough test. It will certainly report any errors caught by SMART, but if the OS is screaming that something is wrong, invest the time to let tools like `fsck` (File System Check) do their work ...

Comment: I ran fsck and e2fsck and there was nothing wrong apparently.

Comment: In recovery mode in Ubuntu is Filesystem always ro you have to remount it rw by yourself

Comment: yeah figured that out. still womdering how to fix this

Comment: did `which systemd-sysusers` something return?

Comment: I just reinstalled ubuntu and it works fine now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had to reinstall ubuntu..